# White listed android app in doze mode

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to make a GPS tracker app.

I don't intent to distribute this app in play store. So, I got full control of the device(and can do manually whitelist).

I would like to know if:

1. Would doze mode be activated if charger is always connected to
   phone?
2. Would sudden jerk or vibration to phone disables doze mode
   after a prolonged inactivity? For example,consider phone placed
   inside a truck and would that vibration (from engine start or
   travelling) be sufficient to get the device from doze to normal
   mode?
3. Will job scheduler service work in doze mode with scheduled
   app manually whitelisted (including GPS and network)?
4. Would phone call to doze mode device changes its state to normal mode?
5. Would sensors like gyro, accelerometer work in doze mode?

Comment: 1. Being on a charger is supposed to prevent Doze mode. 2. At best, I would expect your results to be unreliable. However, they have not documented how much movement is necessary to for the device to be considered active, particularly with the screen off. 3. It should. Part of my hedging with #1 and #3 is that individual device manufacturers might do more aggressive power management than Android does by default.

Comment: oh, I see. Mark, I have added last two questions. Would you care to answer those. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: 4. Presumably, yes, since the screen will light up and stuff. 5. They do not necessarily work when the screen is off, let alone in Doze mode, so I would not expect them to work in Doze mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

> Would doze mode be activated if charger is always connected to phone?

No.

> As soon as the user wakes the device by moving it, turning on the
>   screen, or connecting a charger, the system exits Doze and all apps
>   return to normal activity.

**Question 2:**

> Would sudden jerk or vibration to phone disables doze mode after a
>   prolonged inactivity? For example,consider phone placed inside a truck and would that vibration (from engine start or travelling) be sufficient to get
>   the device from doze to normal mode?

Prior to Android N, Yes. From Android N, no.

> Android 7.0 brings further enhancements to Doze by applying a subset
>   of CPU and network restrictions while the device is unplugged with the
>   screen turned off, but not necessarily stationary, for example, when a
>   handset is traveling in a user’s pocket.

**Question 3**

> Will job scheduler service work in doze mode with scheduled app
>   manually whitelisted (including GPS and network)?

No.

> An app that is whitelisted can use the network and hold partial wake
>   locks during Doze and App Standby. However, **other restrictions still
>   apply to the whitelisted app**, just as they do to other apps. For
>   example, **the whitelisted app’s jobs and syncs are deferred** (on API
>   level 23 and below), and its regular AlarmManager alarms do not fire.

**Question 4**

> Would phone call to doze mode device changes its state to normal mode?

Yes. Due to same reason as Question 1.

**Question 5**

> Would sensors like gyro, accelerometer work in doze mode?

Might not work in Doze mode

For more details on Optimizations in Doze mode, you can refer this [document](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_doze).

Comment: I was not aware of Android N version document update on doze mode.

Comment: "When a device is on battery power, and the screen has been off for a certain time, the device enters Doze and applies the first subset of restrictions" , "Any time the screen is off for a period of time and the device is unplugged, Doze applies a subset of the familiar CPU and network restrictions to apps. " - So, question (1) should be No?

Comment: Oops. You are right. In hurry I wrote for deactivate. Thanks for correcting.